# Broadcasting error in constructing numpy array using a loop

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to construct a matrix using the following loop:

```
import numpy as np

def F_data(x, order):
  X_F = np.zeros((len(x),order))
  for i in range(order):
   if i == 0:
     X_F[:,i] = 1
   if i % 2 != 0:
     X_F[:,i] = np.sin(np.pi*x*i)
   else:
     X_F[:,i] = np.cos(np.pi*x*i)
  return X_F
```

But when I execute the following:

```
x = np.linspace(-1,1,200)
order = 5
X_F = F_data(x, order)
```

I get an error:

```
---> 14      X_F[:,i] = np.cos(np.pi*x*i)
     15   return X_F
     16 

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (200,1) into shape (200)
```

Which I don't understand since my shapes should match

Comment: Are you sure that's the `x` you used?  I don't think there's a problem with your version.  If `x` is (200,) then the insert should be as well.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried your code. It worked fine for me. you just need to upgrade numpy package.

- pip install numpy --upgrade use this command to upgrade numpy.